# Can spring provide concept like job queue

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Example like I have a 25 job and i want to execute 3 job concurrent and after one of the three job complete then next one pick-up from queue.

Answer (score 8):

You can do this with classes in the standard Java library - you don't need Spring for this. Use an `ExecutorService`, for example:

```
class MyJob implements Runnable {

    private final String message;

    MyJob(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println(message);
    }
}

public class Example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Executor service with 3 threads
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        // Submit jobs to be executed
        executorService.execute(new MyJob("testing"));
        executorService.execute(new MyJob("one"));
        executorService.execute(new MyJob("two"));
        executorService.execute(new MyJob("three"));

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes `Spring` provides support for Job scheduling through [Quartz Scheduler](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/). For more information about how Spring is using Quartz, you can go through the [official spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html).

Apart from this, if you want some ready made example, you can go through, [Spring 3 + Quartz Scheduler](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-quartz-scheduler-example/) and [Spring 4 + Quartz Scheduler](http://websystique.com/spring/spring-4-quartz-scheduler-integration-example/).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use the Spring boot: 
Here is a good start with scheduling using Annotation with Spring
https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/

Here is a nice Introduction for Spring Boot with Quartz: http://de.slideshare.net/davidkiss/spring-boot-with-quartz

Good Luck!